# Universal Link works only on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, deeplink, apple-app-site-associate

Morning everyone!
So i just managed to implement universal link to my iOS Project.
I'm using App Search Validation Tool to check it's integrity and i'm having this status at Link to Application:

"Action required
Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAXIA.png

Then i go to this link to check if my apple-app-site-association JSON format is correct. It seems it is, here is the format that I'm using:

```
    {
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/videos"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But still working perfectly on Xcode simulators but not on my iPhone, what am I missing?

Comment: I assume you are trying to deep-link from a web page into your iOS application. Did you configure the Associated Domains Entitlement? 
Here is some info that can help you if you're not sure: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains

Comment: This should also be reflected in your App ID on apple developer portal.

Comment: I believe the domains in entitlements file are already properly implemented:
I set the associated domain in signing & capabilities like this: 
`applinks:my.domain.com`

I also checked the file .entitlements and it has the same domain there.
It should work by now, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some frustrations, it seems like it might take some time to universal link to work after install it on the iPhone. Fortunately Xcode allows it to happen on simulator instantly.

Comment: Any idea how long it takes? I am using flutter for ios development, and completed the setup of universal links; Like in your scenario, it works on simulator but not on a phone. They have mentioned in the documentation that it takes upto 24 hours, but it's been 3 days since I last setup this, but it isn't working yet.